# Windows 10 - WM_IME_NOTIFY receives wParam = 15 which is not in the list of valid Commands. What is this value of 15?

Tags: c++, windows, ime

I am working to implement some custom handling for IME Input on Windows and noticed that some WM_IME_NOTIFY messages have a wParam value of 15 which is not in the list of valid commands as per the following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/wm-ime-notify

What am I missing here? Is there some newer documentation with an updated list of valid commands?

What is this value of 15?

Comment: You _might_ be able to glean something about these from the WinAPI headers. I suspect they are internal (undocumented) messages you can ignore but it does seem strange that they're not mentioned at all.

Comment: There is no value 15 defined by Microsoft. The highest value defined is `IMN_PRIVATE` (14), which is also not documented by MSDN. So 15 is likely an internal message from the IME implementation.

Comment: Prior to posting the question, I did review both documentation (linked previously) and the header imm.h where as @RemyLebeau stated, the last value is (14). Still have no idea what this value of 15 is. Hoping there is some updated documentation or something.

Comment: @Stephan 15 is not an official value from Microsoft, so you are not going to get documentation from there. And no code samples I've found online handle values beyond 13 or 14, so 15 is not a commonly encountered value in general. All the more reason to think that it is likely a private value for the particular IME implementation that your system is using

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am running a stock Windows 10 implementation of my own and getting those values which is why I am puzzled.

Comment: If I figure out what this value is, I will certainly update this question.

Thank you all!